# Particle in a box, quantization of energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, boundary-conditions, discrete

I'm learning about how the energy of matter is quantized like how the energy of light is. My textbook illustrates the concept of quantization with the particle in a box:

> "A particle of mass $m$ moves in one dimension as it bounces back and forth with speed $v$ between the ends of the box of length $L$. We'll assume that the collisions at the ends are perfectly elastic, so the particle's energy--entirely kinetic--never changes."

I don't understand how the particle's energy can be "entirely kinetic." When the particle hits the end of the the box and reverses its direction, isn't there an instance in time where the particle's speed is 0 which would imply that all of its energy is now potential energy and that it's kinetic energy is zero?

Comment: An assumption of the 'particle in a box' model is that infinitely large forces repel the particle if it touches a wall of the box.

Comment: Well, that would have been nice for the book to have mentioned.

Comment: True, as is the case with most introductory high school/college textbooks oversimplifying quantum mechanics. Which book is it? Also, would you like to see the Schrodinger equation solution of the 'particle in a box' model?

Comment: It's called Physics for Scientists and Engineers (3e) by Knight. He just introduced the de Broglie wavelength and he won't be introducing the Schrodinger stuff until the next chapter, so I know nothing about Schrodinger yet.

Answer (score 1):

The walls do not really matter that much here. I would say that the only points that matter to understand that quote are:

1. The confining potential is conservative so that $K+U = constant$
2. The confining potential is virtually flat $U = 0$ almost everywhere inside the box (say 99% of the box) except very close to the walls

These two conditions are enough to say that the total energy of the particle (its value) is the kinetic energy it has in a big fraction of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an image of the 'particle in a box' model:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gsu.edu](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/imgqua/pbox1.gif))</sub>

At the endpoints, you can see that there is an infinite potential outside the boundary of the box and zero potential inside. The unrealistic assumption in this model is that every time the particle reaches the boundary, an infinite force repels it to keep it in the box.

Comment: One more step is needed:  the impulse must be finite, so we have to assume that $F\rightarrow\infty$ and $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$ in such a way that the product $F\Delta t$ remains finite, and since $\Delta t$ is approaching zero, the particle spends "no time" with $v=0$

Comment: Yes, of course. I forgot to mention that the impulse must remain finite.

Answer (score 0):

What I think of what maybe a correct proposition is that when the particle hits the boundary of a box( i am assuming that it is a physical box which is what I interpreted from your question let me know if it is otherwise  ) momentarily all its momentum is transferred to the wall and hence the kinetic energy becomes zero for the ball itself (also if the ball is set in a zero potential energy condition the total energy of the ball at this instance becomes zero).  Then momentum is transferred back from the wall to the ball which causes the change in direction  . Therefore , if the collisions between the ball and the wall are perfectly elastic the ball will keep going back and forth  since the energy will keep shifting between the ball and the wall without any loss . Also , a point to be noted is that though the energy of the ball at the instance can be zero the law of conservation of energy is not violated since the energy of the whole system involved is constant . let me know if this makes sense or is helpful .